# Can sklearn's LabelBinarizer act similarly to DictVectorizer?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have a dataset which includes numerical and categorical features, where the categorical features can contain a list of labels. For example:

```
RecipeId   Ingredients    TimeToPrep
1          Flour, Milk    20
2          Milk           5
3          Unobtainium    100
```

If I only had one Ingeredient per recipe, DictVecorizer would've gracefully handled the encoding to the appropriate dummy variables:

```
from sklearn feature_extraction import DictVectorizer
RecipeData=[{'RecipeID':1,'Ingredients':'Flour','TimeToPrep':20}, {'RecipeID':2,'Ingredients':'Milk','TimeToPrep':5}
,{'RecipeID':3,'Ingredients':'Unobtainium','TimeToPrep':100}
dc=DictVectorizer()
dc.fit_transform(RecipeData).toarray()
```

gives as output:

```
array([[   1.,    0.,    0.,    1.,   20.],
       [   0.,    1.,    0.,    2.,    5.],
       [   0.,    0.,    1.,    3.,  100.]])
```

The integer features are handled correctly while the categorical labels are encoded into boolean features.

However, DictVectorizer can't handle list-valued features and chokes on

RecipeData=[{'RecipeID':1,**'Ingredients':['Flour','Milk']**,'TimeToPrep':20}, {'RecipeID':2,'Ingredients':'Milk','TimeToPrep':5}
,{'RecipeID':3,'Ingredients':'Unobtainium','TimeToPrep':100}

LabelBinarizer handles this correctly but the categorical variables must be extracted and treated separately:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelBinarizer
lb=LabelBinarizer()
lb.fit_transform([('Flour','Milk'), ('Milk',), ('Unobtainium',)])
array([[1, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 1]])
```

And that's the way I do it currently - extract the categorical features that contain lists of labels out of the mixed numerical/categorical input array, transform them with LabelBinarizer and then glue the numerical features back on.

Is there a more elegant way to do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`LabelBinarizer` is intended for class labels, not features (although with the right massaging it will handle categorical features as well).

The intended use of `DictVectorizer` is that you map a data-specific function over samples to extract useful features, the function returning a `dict`. So, the elegant way to solve this is to write a function that flattens your feature dicts and replace lists by individual features with a value of `True`:

```
>>> def flatten_ingredients(d):
...     # in-place version
...     if isinstance(d.get('Ingredients'), list):
...         for ingredient in d.pop('Ingredients'):
...             d['Ingredients=%s' % ingredient] = True
...     return d
... 
>>> RecipeData=[{'RecipeID':1,'Ingredients':['Flour','Milk'],'TimeToPrep':20}, {'RecipeID':2,'Ingredients':'Milk','TimeToPrep':5} ,{'RecipeID':3,'Ingredients':'Unobtainium','TimeToPrep':100}]
>>> map(flatten_ingredients, RecipeData)
[{'Ingredients=Milk': True, 'RecipeID': 1, 'TimeToPrep': 20, 'Ingredients=Flour': True}, {'RecipeID': 2, 'TimeToPrep': 5, 'Ingredients': 'Milk'}, {'RecipeID': 3, 'TimeToPrep': 100, 'Ingredients': 'Unobtainium'}]
```

In action:

```
>>> from sklearn.feature_extraction import DictVectorizer
>>> dv = DictVectorizer()
>>> dv.fit_transform(flatten_ingredients(d) for d in RecipeData).toarray()
array([[   1.,    1.,    0.,    1.,   20.],
       [   0.,    1.,    0.,    2.,    5.],
       [   0.,    0.,    1.,    3.,  100.]])
>>> dv.feature_names_
['Ingredients=Flour', 'Ingredients=Milk', 'Ingredients=Unobtainium', 'RecipeID', 'TimeToPrep']
```

(If I were you, I'd also remove the `RecipeID` since it's extremely unlikely to be a useful feature and it can easily cause overfitting.)

Comment: Thank you, this is much more elegant than what I cobbled together. The IDs are naturally not used in the learning task, they just help me to identify the relevant rows in the transformed array when debugging.